# I used try and except but I wanted if the ValueError error happens not to display the rest of the questions

Tags: python

```
try:
            pergunta_AS2=float(input("Quak nota você tirou na AS2"))
        except ValueError:

                    I wanted that if the problem happens not to show the variables below:
            pergunta_simulado =float(input("Qual foi a sua nota no simulado de ALL:"))
            pergunta_trimestral=float(input("Qual foi a sua nota na trimestral de ALL"))
            pergunta_MTN=float(input("Qual foi a sua terceira nota (MTN) de ALL:"))
```

I wanted that if the problem happens not to show the variables below:

Comment: If you want to execute the 3 last inputs only if the *ValueError* exception has not occurred, you could use the `else` block, as shown in [this article from w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_try_except.asp).

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.